# Magento2 - i18n:collect-phrases override csv file

Tags: magento2, localisation

I've a Magento2 application with A LOT of texts and sometimes I have to add new phrases that need to be translated as well.

To wrap text that needs to be translated I use:

```
<?php echo __("Lorem ipsum ..")?>
```

Then I edit the csv file in i18n theme's folder.

In order to add new string to the file, I run `magento i18n:collect-phrases`, but it overrides the .csv output file in the theme directory, so I lose the old translations.

I think I'm not understanding how to correctly generate and use translation dictionaries, can you pls explain it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2 **i18n:collect-phrases** it will generate translation CSV file from all core CSV text.

If you want to change any core text, you can run :

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases
```

It will collect all translation from the core.

Magento **i18n:collect-phrases** it will use for only first time for collect core translation. Once complete after you can change the text in your theme but no need to use this command after any modification in theme translation. If you run this after any modification in theme then you lose your previously changes.

Magento i18n:collect-phrases this command use for collect core translation and write it in theme.

Comment: okay, but what shall I do when I add new text to my theme?

Comment: Yes you can add your custom text to in your theme.

Comment: and how can I add new string to csv file?

Comment: You can manually write text to csv file.

Comment: It doesn't look like the right way to do it. o,O

Comment: Custom text need to always add to manually.