# How can I automatically collect new translations without overriding already translated strings?

Tags: magento2, localisation, i18n

As far as I understand, there are three steps to adding translations:

1. collect phrases (`bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases ...`) to a CSV file that has two columns, e.g., `"order","order"`
2. replace the second column with the desired translations (e.g., for German `"order","bestellen"`)
3. rename the file to e.g., de_DE.csv and put it in the i18n folder of my theme or module

Now, if my module/theme gets updated and new strings are added that I would like to translate, how do I proceed? If I repeat step 1. and collect phrases into the same file, my existing translations will be overwritten.

For WordPress, [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) allows me to add new translations from a POT file without overwriting previous ones. For Magento, I am not aware of such a tool.

I could of course write a parser that only extracts strings without a translation and adds those to de_DE.csv, but that seems a bit cumbersome - is there a best practices on how to update translation files?

I am aware of question [148062](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148062/magento2-i18ncollect-phrases-override-csv-file), but I don't find the answer particulary helpful.

Comment: Not sure that I understand your problem; What about going to previously created de_DE.csv and adding new translations? I mean, why do you need a system which will grab strings to translate for you?

Comment: That's a lot of manual work and needs to be done every time I add a module or a template. Even just changing a string would require me to update the CSV file. Other frameworks (like WordPress) automate this process.

Comment: So now you have ./bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --magento --output ./var/phrases.csv which collect all phrases, doestn't matter if this phrases been translated before. You need some extra param, like --locale de_DE, it will collect all phrases that not translated for the specified locale. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that would be perfect, does something like that exist?

Comment: Now, I believe, something like that exists. Check my answer, and feel free to ping me if you still have any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have searched over the web and didn't find something that can solve your problem,
but I think such kind of feature will be very useful, so I've written my own solution for this problem: [module-translation-helper](https://github.com/underser/module-translation-helper)

you can install it by composer:

```
composer require underser/module-translation-helper
```

Install the module and rebuild the DI cache:

```
./bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Then you can collect your new translation by using:

```
./bin/magento i18n:translation-helper --locale de_DE  --output ./var/de_DE.csv ./app/code/Vendor/NewModule
```

***Note: This is not self-promotion or something like that if you know something better you can always propose your own solution***

Comment: Wow, fantastic! I'll definitely use that!

Comment: How does one import back the CSV once translated?